# Custom size of molecules in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Is there a way to downsize my molcules in chemfig. `\tiny` and `\small` are not quite what I am looking for. I found `\setchemfig{atomstyle={scale=0.5}}` doesn´t do anything. I want to size it down so that the whole chemical equation fits in one page and that the molecule is shown above the reaction arrow. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    
\setchemfig{atomstyle={scale=0.5}}\chemname{\chemfig{*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-([-3]<-[3]S\rlap{${}^+$}(-[2,,1]{\color{red}C}|{\color{red}H_3})-[-3]-[3]-[-3]C([-2]<NH_2)-[3]([2]=O)-[-3]{\llap{${}^-$}O})-(<:OH)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(-NH_2)=N-)}}{S-Adenosyl-L-methionine}

\tiny\chemname{\chemfig{*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-([-3]<-[3]S\rlap{${}^+$}(-[2,,1]{\color{red}C}|{\color{red}H_3})-[-3]-[3]-[-3]C([-2]<NH_2)-[3]([2]=O)-[-3]{\llap{${}^-$}O})-(<:OH)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(-NH_2)=N-)}}{S-Adenosyl-L-methionine}

\end{document}
```

```
    \chemfig[atomstyle={scale=0.5}]{*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-([-3]<-[3]S\rlap{${}^+$}(-[2,,1]{\color{red}C}|{\color{red}H_3})-[-3]-[3]-[-3]C([-2]<NH_2)-[3]([2]=O)-[-3]{\llap{${}^-$}O})-(<:OH)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(-NH_2)=N-)}


\chemfig[atom style={scale=0.5}]{*6((-X)-A-B-C-D-(-H_3G)-)}
\chemfig[atom style={scale=1}]{*6((-X)-A-B-C-D-(-H_3G)-)
```

[image]
lower left = atom style={scale=0.5}
lower right = atom style={scale=1}

upper one = atomstyle={scale=0.5} but size does not change no matter what value.

Comment: `\chemfig[atom style={scale=0.5}]{...}`

Comment: It works with simple molecules `\chemfig[atom style={scale=0.5}]{*6((-X)-A-B-C-D-(-H_3G)-)}` but fails for some reason with more complicated ones `\chemfig[atomstyle={scale=0.5}]{*6(=N-*5(-N(>*5(-O-([-3]<-[3]S\rlap{${}^+$}(-[2,,1]{\color{red}C}|{\color{red}H_3})-[-3]-[3]-[-3]C([-2]<NH_2)-[3]([2]=O)-[-3]{\llap{${}^-$}O})-(<:OH)-(<:OH)-))-=N-)=-(-NH_2)=N-)}`.

Comment: atom style not atomstyle (with space)

Comment: Sorry my bad. Thanks for the help